# What would cause Gdata Python Client to fail on call to YouTubeVideoQuery in appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, youtube-api, gdata-api, gdata

The following **use** to work as expected on the local development server and on deployment.

```
client = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
gdata.alt.appengine.run_on_appengine(client,deadline=10)
query = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeVideoQuery()

query.vq = search_term
query.orderby = 'viewCount'
query.max_results = '5'

feed = client.YouTubeQuery(query)
```

It **now** only works on the development server but fails on deployment.
(no feed returned)

I don't think the python clent has been updated for the new v2 youtube api, but support is
still there for v1 correct? Still, if it works locally, I can't see why it would fail
when deployed. Has something changed recently that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I found my mistake. Forgot to add back developer key to revised code. Works locally, but gets *quota* errors when doing a query from the appengine servers.